# Create banner/tool bar in java acting like Windows Taskbar

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to create desktop application, a banner / tool bar, in java (I'm using swing in netbeans) and I want it to act same as windows Task bar, means desktop icons will rearrange according to banner position.

How to do so?

Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 1):

one of way is use `JWindow` or Modal and un_decorated `JDialog`, for example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SlideText_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final JWindow window = new JWindow();
        final JPanel windowContents = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("A window that is pushed into view..........");
        windowContents.add(label);
        window.add(windowContents);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        final int desiredWidth = window.getWidth();
        window.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        window.setSize(0, window.getHeight());
        window.setVisible(true);
        Timer timer = new Timer(15, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int newWidth = Math.min(window.getWidth() + 1, desiredWidth);
                window.setSize(newWidth, window.getHeight());
                windowContents.setLocation(newWidth - desiredWidth, 0);
                if (newWidth >= desiredWidth) {
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    window.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout()); //restore original layout
                    window.validate();
                    window.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    private SlideText_1() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thing is that it's only hovers above desktop items, I want desktop items (icons and such) react to the banner and will not collide with it.

Answer (score 1):

Shahar asked this question on my behalf. I thought that it could be done using pure Java, but sadly as far as I know, in this case, Java is a dead end.

You need to use windows API and for that you will need to use Java Native Interface (JNI).

Best way is to create a DLL using C or C++ (use the header windows) and import it into the Java code.